# First time with tables/html email - text padding issue

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, padding

This is my first attempt at HTML emails, and also using tables. I've found a decent collection of templates through Mailchimp which I've edited down to be relatively close to what I need. I do have one issue though: the beginning of the text is pushed far to the right. How do I fix this?

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div mc:edit="std_content00">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/405/325" style="max-width:405px;" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/218/30" width="218" height="30" style="padding:30px 0px 30px 0px;" />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vehicula aliquet nisl vulputate tincidunt. Nulla.  </div>                                                       </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a paragraph:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div mc:edit="std_content00">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/405/325" style="max-width:405px;" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/218/30" width="218" height="30" style="padding:30px 0px 30px 0px;" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vehicula aliquet nisl 
vulputate tincidunt. Nulla.</p>  </div>                                                       </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/fVKbr/

style="padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;"

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/fVKbr/

Answer (score 0):

```
style="padding:30px 0px 30px 0px;" />
```

to

```
style="padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;" />
```

or whatever suits you.

The padding values are for top, right, bottom, left, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You have padding in your image, and that hides the fact that it is in the same table row as the text.

Use the following to get the text aligned:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div mc:edit="std_content00">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/405/325" style="max-width:405px;" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/218/30" width="218" height="30" style="padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;" /><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vehicula aliquet nisl vulputate tincidunt. Nulla.  </div>                                                       </td>
</tr>
```